# Why Does My Twitch IRC Bot not Connect?

Tags: bots, irc, twitch

So I decided to try and write a twitch IRC bot just for the sake of experience. So far I've learnt a whole lot but now I've hit a road block and can't seem to get the bot to connect.

I have an IRC client that can connect to the twitch irc fine, though I can't ping irc.twitch.tv
My bot uses the PircBotX framework as it's base and so far all It should do is connect to the server but it doesn't. I got everything setup in eclipse and everything seems fine but the bot never actually connects. It tries and tries but never seems to get through.

I'm not sure why it's not working. I've also port forwarded the port just in case it needed that on the router but no luck.
When I run the bot in eclipse it starts tries to connect then stops running.

I've been piecing things together from pircbotx's documentation, this bot's code: https://github.com/MattsMc/MankiniBot and this youtube series I found: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a1WDUKI5-PI. Any help you can provide would be amazing. Thanks.

P.S: I changed the OAUTH code so no need to worry on that :)

Basically here's my code:

```html
package firedingo.project.bot;



import com.google.common.collect.*;
import com.google.guava.*;
import org.pircbotx.Configuration;
import org.pircbotx.PircBotX;


public class TheDingoPack {
 private int count;
 
 //starting config again in case config derp is issue, will need clean up HERE
 Configuration<PircBotX> Config = new Configuration.Builder<PircBotX>()
   .setServerPassword(firedingo.project.bot.reference.Reference.OAUTH)
   .setName(firedingo.project.bot.reference.Reference.NICK)
   .setLogin(firedingo.project.bot.reference.Reference.NICK)
   .setAutoNickChange(true)
   .setServerHostname(firedingo.project.bot.reference.Reference.HOST)
   .setServerPort(firedingo.project.bot.reference.Reference.PORT)
   
   .addAutoJoinChannel(firedingo.project.bot.reference.Reference.BOTCHAN)
   .buildConfiguration();
 
 //Constructor to actually create the bot
 public TheDingoPack() {
  PircBotX TheDingoPack = new PircBotX(Config);
 try {
  TheDingoPack.startBot();
  System.out.println("Attempting To Connect");
 }
 catch(Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Connection Failed - Error Thrown");
 }

 
}
 //realized constructor needed a call so added it here. Nearly derped :P
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   new TheDingoPack();
  }
}
```

```html
package firedingo.project.bot.reference;

public class Reference {

 //Connection Details As Constants For Easy Customizability
 public static final String NICK = "thedingopack";
 public static final String HOST = "irc.twitch.tv";
 public static final String OAUTH = "6lw8eg2zw81pmpj09kbr9pa62d006f";
 public static final int PORT = 6667;
 //these two channels can be changed as necessary, extras can also be added.
 public static final String BOTCHAN = "#thedingopack";
 public static final String MODCHAN = "#firedingo99365";
 
  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried answering your question here, but Stack Overflow would only let me post two links so here's the short of it...

I copy/pasted your code into my environment, replaced with my bot stats and ran it, I ran into no issue whatsoever. This leads me to one of two options...

A. You don't have an account for the bot (I find this unlikely as you have an OAuth code)

B. Your environment is not setup properly, did you add the extra packages found on the [download page](https://code.google.com/p/pircbotx/wiki/Downloads)to your project?

If not and you don't know how, or you just want to know exactly what .jars to add (as a couple packages have a bunch of pointless ones) I made a tutorial on how to set it up. You can find it [here](http://youtu.be/zSAQTtBTXN0).

Answer (score 0):

what i can remember you need to put the full oath code so like this

```
public static final String OAUTH = "oath:6lw8eg2zw81pmpj09kbr9pa62d006f";
```